# Opening live USB from GRUB prompt

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, system-installation

While trying to upgrade to 14.04, in a series of unwise moves I ended up destroying my Ubuntu installation. So I used a live USB to mount my original disk drive and recover my files, before reinstalling everything. So far, OK.

The problem is that when I restarted my PC (possibly because I forgot to unmount the disk?), I was directed to the GRUB prompt, and I don't know how to open the live USB or the Boot-Repair at the prompt.

I don't know if it is helpful, but 'ls' returns:

```
(hd0) (hd1, msdos1) (hd1) (hd1, gpt3) (hd1, gpt2) (hd1, gpt1) (cd0) error: failure reading sector 0x0 from 'cd0'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your usb device to be the first in boot priority from your BIOS menu, leave the usb in before you boot or reboot. You should be able to access boot repair from the live USB this way. From all I have gathered, grub doesn't boot live systems unless they have been previously installed to do so. If there is a way do do it, I would like to know also.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your bios to boot the usb drive first, then let it go. You may have to change ownership of your files to move them to another drive.